# Creating filter columns on dynamic table using Arraylist in java

Tags: java, ajax, jstl

I am creating a dynamic table by iterating arraylist using c:forEach jstl tag. Now after rendering data on table, I need to create drop down on each column where if I select any value in drop down, I can render that data on table again.
I dont want to do form submit. Please let me know if I can achieve this using AJAX, if yes then please provide me guidelines.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this with Ajax.  Note: You're asking the wrong question; you're more likely to get help when you put more effort (i.e.: showing what you've tried) and then asking for help.  Good luck.

Comment: you can easily do this with the popular jquery library called Datatable for this type of thing.

Comment: See this http://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html